# How to hide group heading when child elements not present on user search

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We added angular search feature for subjects. But I would like to hide subjects category if search keyword matching subjects are not present in respective group. Eg: We should hide "Sports & Arts" category when user searched for "Ma" keyword. Please refer plunker link for code - http://plnkr.co/edit/V9X1e7QeZaELMNkh4Ucd?p=preview
Help appreciated.

```
<div class="search">
                <label for="subjectSearch">Search: </label>
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type here to search" class="form-control search-input" ng-model="searchText"/>
        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div ng-repeat="subjects in groupsList track by $index">
                <p class="category" style="background:#ddd;font-weight:bold">{{subjects.subjectHeading}}</p>
                <p class="subject-list" ng-repeat="subject in subjects.subjects | filter:searchText">
                    <label for="{{subject}}">
                        <input ng-model="selectedGroups[$parent.$index].subCategory[$index]" type="checkbox" id="{{subject}}" name="{{subject}}" data-name="{{subject}}" class="subject" ng-true-value="'{{subject}}'" ng-init="checked=''" ng-false-value="''">{{subject}}
                    </label>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

angular code

```
var employeeApp = angular.module("EmployeeApp",[]);
employeeApp.controller("empCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.query = {}
    $scope.queryBy = '$'
    $scope.groupsList = [
    {
    "subjectHeading":"Academic",
    "subjects": [
      "Maths",
      "Computer science"
      ]
  },
  {
    "subjectHeading":"Sports & Arts",
    "subjects":[
      "Tennis",
      "FootBall",
      "Dance"
    ]
  }
];
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-if with filter` to show/Hide SubjectHeading.

Like this

```
<p class="category" ng-if="subjects.subjects | filter : searchText" style="background:#ddd;font-weight:bold">{{subjects.subjectHeading}}</p>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2lM9Uhf3BKmKF5PGAv4h?p=preview)

OR

You can use `$filter` to filter the records and display filtered information only.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="empCtrl">
    <div class="search">
        <label for="subjectSearch">Search: </label>
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Type here to search" class="form-control search-input" ng-model="searchText" ng-change="change(searchText)"/>
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div ng-repeat="subjects in mirrorGroupList track by $index">
            <p class="category" style="background:#ddd;font-weight:bold">{{subjects.subjectHeading}}</p>
            <p class="subject-list" ng-repeat="subject in subjects.subjects">
                <label for="{{subject}}">
                    <input ng-model="selectedGroups[$parent.$index].subCategory[$index]" type="checkbox" id="{{subject}}" name="{{subject}}" data-name="{{subject}}" class="subject" ng-true-value="'{{subject}}'" ng-init="checked=''" ng-false-value="''">{{subject}}
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**ngController**

```
var employeeApp = angular.module("EmployeeApp",[]);
employeeApp.controller("empCtrl",function($scope,$filter){
    $scope.query = {}
    $scope.queryBy = '$'
    $scope.groupsList = [
      {
        "subjectHeading":"Academic",
        "subjects": [
          "Maths",
          "Computer science"
        ]
      },
      {
        "subjectHeading":"Sports & Arts",
        "subjects":[
          "Tennis",
          "FootBall",
          "Dance"
        ]
      }
    ];

    // create mirror copy for filtering information
    $scope.mirrorGroupList = angular.copy($scope.groupsList);

    $scope.change = function(data){
      $scope.mirrorGroupList = $filter('filter')($scope.groupsList,{$ : data});
    }
});
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h2ai6uGEHr0RWwnypHRX?p=preview)

> Note : Here, I am created mirror copy of groupsList and passing filtered value to mirror copy and each time when searchText is change, I am filtering information based on original **$scope.groupsList** array, so the original information remain always as it is.

To search on specific key only then ypu have to replace `$` with other key
Like

```
$scope.change = function(data){
// replaced `$` with subjects
  $scope.mirrorGroupList = $filter('filter')($scope.groupsList,{subjects : data});
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I see below error on console while entering keyword on search field: 
angular.js:8296 Error: [$rootScope:infdig]

I have huge list of subjects. Its breaking with below error:
angular.js:13424 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: Yes, its because, we are comparing same object again and gain, let me modified my answer :)

Comment: Works great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome @Nikki  :)

Comment: Is there anyway we can skip group names (Academic) from search list? Currently when I enter "Acad" keyword, it shows "academic" category. But I need to apply search for sub categories alone and show nothing if user searches for "academic"

Comment: Yes, you can replace `$` with `subjects`.