# Filter by multilevel Deep Property

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a collection somewhat like mentioned below:-

```
    [
        {
        rootGroup: "group1",
        secondGroup: false,
        items: [
                 {name:"Ram"},
                 {name:"Mohan"},
                 {name:"Shyam"},
               ]
        },
        {
        rootGroup: "group2",
        secondGroup: true,
        secondLevelGroups:[
           {
           group: "gp1"
           items: [
                    {name:"Ganesh"},
                    {name:"Sita"},
                    {name:"Gita"},
                  ]
           },
           {
           group: "gp2"
           items: [
                    {name:"Soham"},
                    {name:"Vikas"},
                    {name:"Ashish"},
                  ]
           }
        ]
        }
    ]
```

Now I want to filter on name. So for example if the filter value is **"am"** then the output should be like as below.

```
    [
        {
        rootGroup: "group1",
        secondGroup: false,
        items: [
                 {name:"Ram"},`
                 {name:"Shyam"},
               ]
        },
        {
        rootGroup: "group2",
        secondGroup: true,
        secondLevelGroups:[
           {
           group: "gp2"
           items: [
                    {name:"Soham"},
                  ]
           }
        ]
        }
    ]
```

*I want to do it using angularjs filter*

Comment: post the HTML code that display the json data

Comment: check [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342285/how-to-hide-group-heading-when-child-elements-not-present-on-user-search/41342425#41342425)

Comment: @NagaveerGowda the inner part of html is not related to the question. just the outerpart is required. which is to setup the initial data using fiter. and I don't know how can I use the filter in this case

Comment: @AyushKumar You to write an angular custom filter to search multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the extension angular filter: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for